# eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen : Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipselink

I was working on a project for school with Mockito, JPA and JavaFX. Everything worked until I added the module-info.java into my IntelliJ. We needed to make an Eclipse project first for the school, but I code in IntelliJ. I'm wondering what the problem could be. I'm searching all night but didn't find anything that could help.

Info and files:

Error message:

```java
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\usr\mylibrary2020\jpa\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.7.5.v20191016-ea124dd158.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.2.7.5.v20191016.ea124dd158: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
```

module-info.java:

```java
module Project.Java {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires org.mockito;
    requires mockito.junit.jupiter;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.params;

    requires java.persistence;

    opens start to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
    opens gui to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;
}
```

[dependencies project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMPtp.png)

[eclipselink sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMfq3.png)

Comment: Probably there is an issue with underscore in dependency "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.7.5.v20191016-ea124dd158.jar".

Comment: When you put a JAR on the modulepath, the module name is given by the contained `module-info.class`. If the JAR does not contain a `module-info.class`, then the module name is given in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` by `Automatic-Module-Name: ...`. If both are missing, like in your case (probably because you have outdated dependencies), then the module name is derived from the JAR file name which might fail (like in your case) since the module name must not start with a digit. So, try to update your dependencies and if this does not help, rename the JAR(s). Eclipse would have told you that.